# Blocking certain websites using hosts file Windows/Mac

Tags: internet

I have a certain problem with blocking certain websites using the hosts file on Windows/Mac

Basically i added several websites in the hosts file like this
127.0.0.1 xxxxx.com and as expected using a browser I cannot access the said websites.

Problem is, I am doing this to simulate the internet disconnect for my application which seems to still work even with that website blocked.

Basically what it does is put a file on a cloud storage and downloads a file from that cloud storage. I cannot go with the browser to the download/upload links but the application somehow still is able to upload/download files from that website.

This is the format I tried to use in the hosts file:

127.0.0.1 xxxx.com 
127.0.0.1 yy.xxxx.com

So what exactly am I doing wrong? or is there any other way of simulating a dropped internet connection without the use of other 3rd party applications?

Comment: Questions about host configuration are off topic here. You can consider asking this on [su].

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper firewall to block access to required endpoints. Using hosts file is unreliable, as not all applications are using it to resolve hostnames to IP addresses. A starting point can be Windows Firewall.

If you want to know what IP endpoints application is accessing you can use netstat (in all Win PCs) or Wireshark (need to download).